# Javascript - Transition End isn't firing

Tags: javascript, animation, css-transitions

I got this working before, but cannot tell why currently the `transitionend` events aren't firing. Code in jsfiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/rNzdt/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by replacing the `transitionend` with the `animationend` events since you are using CSS3 animation properties rather than transitions.

Here is your modified JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rNzdt/3/